# Inception-v1 vs Inception-Resnet-V1

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, resnet, deep-residual-networks

Like the title says, is there any difference between the two? I think the original inception v1 model does not have Res Blocks, but maybe I'm wrong. Are they the same thing?

Comment: They are not the same thing. You can read [a nice summary of Inception models here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-guide-to-the-versions-of-the-inception-network-7fc52b863202).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same?

Inception-ResNet is hybrid module inspired both by inception and the performance of resnet. There are further two sub-versions of Inception-ResNet, namely v1 and v2. Inception-ResNet v2 has higher accuracy and computational cost as compared to Inception-ResNet v1 (https://ai.googleblog.com/2016/08/improving-inception-and-image.html).

Answer (score 1):

They are different. Training with residual connections accelerates the training of Inception and may outperform similarly expensive Inception without residual connections.